# Not able to properly see widgets inside JFace dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have a JFace dialog which contains a Label , Text and Button side by side respectively.
I have set the initial size of the dialog and in my machine i have the dialog in the way i wanted.

But on another machine i only partially see the button.

This is how i have overriden the createDialogArea method.

```
@Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) 
{
    Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    GridLayout gridLayout = (GridLayout) container.getLayout();
    gridLayout.numColumns = 3;

    new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    new Label(container, SWT.NONE);

    Label fileLabel = new Label(container, SWT.NONE);
    fileLabel.setText("File Name :");

    fileText = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER);
    GridData fileTextGD = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
    fileTextGD.widthHint = 319;
    fileText.setLayoutData(fileTextGD);
    fileText.setEnabled(false);

    browseButton = new Button(container, SWT.NONE);
    GridData browseButtonGD = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
    browseButtonGD.widthHint = 28;
    browseButton.setLayoutData(browseButtonGD);
    browseButton.setText("...");

return container;
}
```

What would be the problem?

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

The `widthHint` values you are using are probably too small for the font used on the second machine. Do not use `widthHint`, let the `GridLayout` work out the sizes for you.